# <label> element splits to multiple lines

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a `<label>` element in my ASP.NET core MVC project, that splits to multiple lines instead of showing in a single line. I've inspected the element in google chrome to see what css is being applied. It is getting it from my custom.css class. Below is my custom.css file.

```
body {
    padding: 1em;
    font-family: Arial, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1{
    margin-top:0;
    color: navy;
}

label{
    display: inline-block;
    width = 50em;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

div{
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    column-width = 300px;
}
```

The css in the inspect element is as below.
[image: UI with inspect element displayed next to it.]

I've tried updating the custom.css files in the code, but it still somehow picks the same values for css. Tried cleaning and rebuilding the code. Still doesn't work.
However, when I un-select the width property(as shown below) in inspect element, it shows as expected. I'm removing the `width` property from custom.css file but it is still coming up during run.

[image: The width property unselected in Inspect element]

I'm unable to explain why this is happening and how to get the label in a single line. Tried updating the custom.css file in code and the changes simply don't reflect. Why has this been happening and how to fix it.
If you're interested in the entire code [source code](https://github.com/ArpitChinmay/Ch02Ex01-FutureValue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your source code link is not working so only just looking at your screenshots i'm suggesting the following changes, see if it helps you.

---

since you are using tag instead of a class the other classes or id selectors may be applied to your label width, the CSS selector specificity applied(or decrease) on the following order,

1. ID
2. class
3. tags

but don't use ID for this purpose since it's hard to override them in the future, use classes instead.

for now just set the width of the label as 100% so it will take full space of available width and also add !important to make it as high-priority origin that can override any inline styles or other overriding class styles.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width = 100% !important;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

Comment: I know I sound very stupid when I say this, but I shutdown my computer for the day. Restarted it the next day and it somehow started to work as expected without any changes. But your changes worked as well.